# How to merge two tables using single query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables named receipt, receiptdet. The receipt table store record of the receipt information while the receiptdet stores the fees details in that receipt.
Table receipt:

### receiptno | payor | amount

66              | 333     | 1600
67              | 332     | 1500
68              | 215     | 300

Table receiptdet:

### receiptno | fee | amount

66              | 21  | 50
66              | 33  | 50
66              | 55  | 1500
67              | 55  | 1500
68              | 12  | 100
68              | 44  | 100
68              | 22  | 100

Table fees:

### Id  | code | inassess

12 | Xbre  | 0
21 | Drop | 0
22 | Stest | 0
33 | Perm | 0
44 | Afee  | 0
55 | TFee  | 1

I want a query that will display records based on the selected field if "INASSESS" field is either 0 or 1  AND SUM THE TOTAL AMOUNT ON RECEIPDET table.

```
DESIRED OUTPUT
```

receiptno | payor | SUM(receiptdet.amount) | inassess
66               | 333    | 1500                                      | 1
67               | 332    | 1500                                      | 1

OR

receiptno | payor | SUM(receiptdet.amount) | inassess

66               | 333    | 100             | 0
68               | 215    | 300             | 0

so far i have to working separate query for both table. and i want to make it as one single query if someone can help me i will greatly appreciate it. thanks in advance

```
SELECT
    receipt.receiptno,
    receipt.amount
FROM
    receipt ORDER
BY LENGTH(receipt.receiptno), receipt.receiptno

SELECT
    Sum(receiptdet.amount),
    receiptdet.student,
    feetype.inassess,
    receiptdet.receiptno
FROM
    receiptdet
    Left Join fees ON receiptdet.fee = fees.id
    Left Join feetype ON fees.feetype = feetype.id
WHERE
    feetype.inassess =  '0' AND
    receiptdet.receiptno =  '66'
```

Comment: have you tried using joins

Comment: When you call a query, you don't exactly create an entirely new table that is stored on disk. You need to call "CREATE TABLE" to do so

Comment: i've tried using joins in my second query, but i want to merge the two query to get my desired output above.

Comment: Otherwise, you see if you can call a `SELECT` within another `SELECT`, using the inner query to slim down the data before the outer `SELECT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `JOINs` to put all the tables together by their linking columns, then use `GROUP BY` to group the data according to `receiptno` and `inassess`. One query will give you all the data you require:

```
SELECT r.receiptno, r.payor, SUM(rd.amount) AS fees, f.inassess
FROM receipt r
LEFT JOIN receiptdet rd ON rd.receiptno = r.receiptno
JOIN fees f ON f.id = rd.fee
GROUP BY f.inassess, r.receiptno
```

For your sample data, this gives:

```
receiptno   payor   fees    inassess
66          333     100     0
68          215     300     0
66          333     1500    1
67          332     1500    1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/935ef2/2)

Comment: this one did the trick. all i need is to add WHERE clause whether i want to display inassess = 1 or = 0. thanks man, appreciate it much